# Can't get contents of certain node from XML file into vba

Tags: xml, vba, parsing, ms-access

I'm trying to get a certain node from an XML-file via VBA. There is a condition in place. If node "Boolean.text" = "false" then I need to have contents of node "Comment" however, with the code i'm using, i constantly get error message "Runtime error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set" on line "If (goodBad.hasChildNodes) Then" I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I also have the feeling that i'm using way to complex code for this rather simple request.

Hope somebody can give me some guidance.

```vb
Sub ReadXMLFile2()
    Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim strXMLFilePath As String
    Dim list As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim resp As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim goodFalse As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim goodBad As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim reason As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim textNodes As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim attr As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strReason As String

    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    strXMLFilePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Test.xml"

    With xDoc
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = True

        If Not xDoc.Load(strXMLFilePath) Then
            Debug.Print .parseError.reason, .parseError.ErrorCode
        End If
    End With

    Set list = xDoc.selectNodes("//ToBeCheckedResp/CheckResp/Resp")

    For Each resp In list
        Set attr = resp.Attributes.getNamedItem("status")

        If (Not attr Is Nothing) Then
            Debug.Print attr.Text
        End If

        If resp.hasChildNodes Then
            For Each childNode In resp.childNodes
                Set goodFalse = childNode.selectSingleNode("Boolean")
                Debug.Print goodFalse.Text
            Next childNode
        End If

        If goodFalse.Text = "true" Then
            strReason = ""
        ElseIf goodFalse.Text = "false" Then
            If resp.hasChildNodes Then
                Set goodBad = resp.selectSingleNode("False")
                If (goodBad.hasChildNodes) Then
                    Set reason = goodBad.selectSingleNode("Why")
                    If reason.hasChildNodes Then
                        Set textNodes = reason.selectNodes("Comment")
                        For Each node In textNodes
                            strReason = strReason & " " & node.Text
                        Next node
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next resp
    Set xDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

XML file used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ToBeCheckedResp>
 <CheckResp>
  <Resp status="completed">
   <Value>
    <Boolean>true</Boolean>
    <Good>
     <Example>Test1</Example>
    </Good>
   </Value>
  </Resp>
  <Resp status="completed">
   <Value>
    <Boolean>false</Boolean>
    <False>
     <Why>
      <Comment>Reason why boolean is false.</Comment>
     </Why>
    </False>
   </Value>
  </Resp>
 </CheckResp>
</ToBeCheckedResp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```vb
>         Set goodBad = resp.selectSingleNode("False")
>         If (goodBad.hasChildNodes) Then
> ```

Error 91 here means `goodBad` is `Nothing`, which means `selectSingleNode` yielded no node named `False` under `resp`.

It looks like you want the `Value` node; presumably `selectSingleNode` won't traverse child nodes / descendants to seek the node name you've given, and this `<Value>` node is in the way.

So, select the `<Value>` node, and then `selectSingleNode` from *that* node. Or, use another method that *does* traverse descendants to find a particular node.

Either way, methods that can return `Nothing` should not be assumed to always return a valid object reference.

If execution can reasonably resume without the node you want, then you want to guard against `Nothing` to prevent making an illegal member call against an invalid object reference:

```vb
    Set goodBad = resp.selectSingleNode("False")
    If Not goodBad Is Nothing Then
        If (goodBad.hasChildNodes) Then
            '...
        End If
    Else
        'goodBad node doesn't exist. What now?
        '...
    End If
```

Otherwise, you can make the assumption explicit with `Debug.Assert`:

```vb
    Set goodBad = resp.selectSingleNode("False")
    Debug.Assert Not goodBad Is Nothing
    If (goodBad.hasChildNodes) Then
```

If the assertion isn't validated, then execution pauses right there and you can debug and resume.

As for the complexity, it stems from essentially hard-coding the node hierarchy (`resp` is the parent of `goodBad`, etc.) and traversing the nodes individually. You could probably simplify it all with more fine-tuned `selectNodes` XPath queries.

Comment: I now see my mistake thanks to your comment. I skipped the "Value" node indeed in the code, therefore it's logical there is an error thrown. I've changed my code, added the value node in the nested if loop and now code is working like a charm. Thank you!